# Export dynamically created table from javascript to Excel

Tags: javascript, export-to-excel, httpcontext, pagemethods

I am working on a project that dynamically creates an html table with javascript.  Once this table is created I need to be able to export it to excel through a button click.  I have tried a few things already, but they haven't worked for me.

1. I tried doing a simple export from javascript by creating the Active X object, but that setting is locked down in IE so our browsers will not work with Active X.
2. I tried exporting to excel from a code behind function using the HttpContext class but since the table is created dynamically, the server doesn't see it.
3. My final method, and I was sure that this was going to work, was I used AJAX via a pagemethod to export the table to excel.  I was going to create an array of the table in javascript and pass it to the pagemethod.  But before I got to this step, I created a pagemethod that exported a simpe "Test" file to excel.  It worked as a method called from a button click, so I figured it would from a pagemethod as well.  It didn't :(  It runs and completes the pagemethod, but doesn't open excel or export anything.  No errors and the success function is executed.

Here is the code:

```
<System.Web.Service.WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function exportTable(ByVal title As String) As String
HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContext()
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename="TEST.xls")
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<?xml version='1.0'?>")
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<ss:Workbook xmlns:ss='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet'>")
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<ss:Worksheet ss:Name='sheet1'>")
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<ss:Table>")
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<ss:Row>")
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type='String'>TEST</ss:Data></ss:Cell>")
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</ss:Row>")
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</ss:Table>")
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</ss:Worksheet>")
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</ss:Workbook>")
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()

Return 0
End Function
```

My page method call is:

```
function exportToExcel(title) {
PageMethods.exportTable(title, exportSuccess, exportFailure)
}
```

The exportSuccess function is a simple alert, which is firing.  I take that to mean that the pageMethod is executing without errors, but that it can't open excel or ... something.

I eventually want to pass in an array and loop through it to add the rows and data.  I've done this with a non dynamic table and it works.  I'm also going to use the title to define the filename, but for testing reasons, I've named it TEST.xls.

I copied and pasted the HttpContext code into a button click event and it worked fine with a static table, so I don't think there are any problems with that.  But I have been known to be wrong.

I guess my question is can a PageMethod export to excel or use the HttpContext class?  Is there a better/easier way to do this?

Please keep in mind that I cannot use ActiveX objects and all customers are required to use IE.

Thanks for your help, and I'm sorry if this has already been covered.  I searched but didn't find anything.  If it has, could you please point me to the post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've buckled under pressure and decided to do it a different way.  I think that ajax does not play well with response.write.

I created an asp:hiddenfield control.  Then when the ajax was called to generate the table, I populated it's value with a pipe delimeted string representing the rows and columns of the table.  So `cell1|cell2||cell1|cell2||cell1|cell2`.

Then I created an on_click method for a button and was able to use the same code from the function above.  To populate the table I just replace the "TEST" by parsing the hiddenfield value.

I decided to post this just in case anyone else was having an issue with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you send out the Excel MIME header, followed by an HTML table, EXCEL should load it as it it were a spreadsheet.